# Mobile robot simulation on 3Dcurved surface

Tags: navigation

I am trying to simulate the position and orientation of a mobile robot driving across an arbitrary 3D curved surface.

Ideally the final program is able to load an arbitrary 3D shape, initialize the robot on the shape and output the robot position and orientation based on the forward- and steering control inputs received by the robot.

I am completely new to ROS.

The simulation of a mobile robot on a 2D surface seems relatively simple to implement using ROS2 and Gazebo. However, I have not found a solution to do the same on a curved surface. Can anyone recommend any ROS2 modules or packages that can be used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an sdf "world" file for gazebo that replaces the ground plane with a different geometric object. This can be a primitive shape like `cylinder`, or a more complex shape defined by `heightmap` or `mesh`. Make sure you understand the different purpose of sdf's `visual` and `collision` geometry.

Gazebo publishes the current pose of the objects, so you can get the robot pose from the model state.